# special characters in url using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, special-characters

The idea is to use www.example.com/admin/#!/12345 as www.example.com/admin/user.php?id=12345

This is the rewrite rule Im trying, but this doesn't seem to work

```
RewriteRule ^admin/#!/(.*)  www.example.com/admin/user.php?id=$2
```

How do I include such special characters ?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `#` is URLs. The browser will interpret it as a fragment identifier and never even send it (or the following part of the URL) to the server.

Comment: Well the reason why I had this idea is,twitter handles it using #!

Comment: @userD Twitter, as any other site, handles it locally (in a browser) using JavaScript (uses it when sending specific AJAX request). Fragment identifier (the `#` char and everything after it) will NOT be sent to a server by browser. Even if you send it to a server somehow (using custom code), such request will either be rejected or cleaned up.